# how to limit the column or fields to only a sepecafic role in views Drupal?

Tags: drupal-views

I have created a view of basic pages content type in drupal and I want to make visible the title field in a view to only admin user and all other fields or column should be visible to all other users including admin. please any one have idea about this?

Comment: At least you should write which programming language and framework you are using.

Comment: Oh sorry, it is related to Drupal Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved now,
solution: create a php field and add following snippet.

roles)) {
    print '$'. $data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_name_to_display['und'][0]['value'];
    }else{
    print "no access";
    }



?>